# folder structure to json with python(unicode)

Tags: python, json, struct, io

This program creates a folder/file structure in json
    #!/usr/bin/env python

```
import os
import errno
import json
import sys


def path_hierarchy(path):
   hierarchy = {
       'type': 'folder',
       'name': os.path.basename(path),
       'path': path,
   }

   try:
       hierarchy['children'] = [
           path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
           for contents in os.listdir(path)
       ]
   except OSError as e:
       if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
           raise
       hierarchy['type'] = os.path.splitext(path)[1]
       if hierarchy['type'] == "":
           hierarchy['type'] = "Unknown"
   return hierarchy

if __name__ == '__main__':


try:
    directory = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    directory = os.getcwd()

fo = open("output.json", "w")
fo.write(json.dumps(path_hierarchy(directory), indent=2, sort_keys=False,))
fo.close()
```

It is actually working but a can't make it work with Greek and Japanesse characters. This is the output of the file.Is it an encoding issue or is it something with the json class in python. I use python3 so everything should be unicode but still...

```
{
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "name": ".name",
            "type": "Unknown",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea\\.name"
          },
          {
            "name": "encodings.xml",
            "type": ".xml",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea\\encodings.xml"
          },
          {
            "name": "JsonFileStruct.iml",
            "type": ".iml",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea\\JsonFileStruct.iml"
          },
          {
            "name": "misc.xml",
            "type": ".xml",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea\\misc.xml"
          },
          {
            "name": "modules.xml",
            "type": ".xml",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea\\modules.xml"
          },
          {
            "name": "workspace.xml",
            "type": ".xml",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea\\workspace.xml"
          }
        ],
        "name": ".idea",
        "type": "folder",
        "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\.idea"
      },
      {
        "name": "main.py",
        "type": ".py",
        "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\main.py"
      },
      {
        "name": "output.json",
        "type": ".json",
        "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\output.json"
      },
      {
        "name": "second.py",
        "type": ".py",
        "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\second.py"
      },
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "\u03ba\u03b1\u03bb\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf.json",
            "type": ".json",
            "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\\u03ba\u03b1\u03ba\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf\\\u03ba\u03b1\u03bb\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf.json"
          }
        ],
        "name": "\u03ba\u03b1\u03ba\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf",
        "type": "folder",
        "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\\u03ba\u03b1\u03ba\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf"
      },
      {
        "name": "\u03ba\u03b1\u03bb\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf.json",
        "type": ".json",
        "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct\\\u03ba\u03b1\u03bb\u03cc\u03c0\u03b1\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf.json"
      }
    ],
    "name": "JsonFileStruct",
    "type": "folder",
    "path": "I:\\Development\\Python\\JsonFileStruct"
  }
```